# Can someone please Identity this tail light?

Tags: part-identification, tail-lights

While I was working someone hit my car while it was parked. Can someone please help me identify the car by part of the tail light that was left behind? Thanks so much[image]

Comment: I think that it will be difficult to identify by that small piece; I also think that it won't solve your problem even if you do identify the make and model. Even if you had the car in front of you and the damage was obvious, it doesn't *prove* that the person driving the car today was driving it when the incident occurred; technically you can't hold the person responsible. If it were me I would probably just get on with fixing my car, filing an insurance claim if the damage exceeded my comprehensive policy deductible.